# Is this the same thing as some simple discrete probability distribution?

Tags: probability, reference-request, markov-chains

I want to count the number of trials until one success in a sequence where the success probability is increased with each failure. For each trial, the success probability is $1-\binom{k+1+i}{k-1}^{-1}$ for $i=1,2,\dots$

Do I need to model this with some Markov chain or is there some elementary distribution that I can turn to?